# Motion Tracking Markers don't show up!

Tags: tracking, marker

I just got Blender 2.8 (ok, I got it a long time ago but it's my first time trying it out).
I watched a tutorial on Motion Tracking ("Camera tracking basics (in blender 2.8)" on YouTube), and I followed all the directions; Exported the video to image sequences, imported into "Motion Tracking" on "VFX" mode, added trackers (the only difference is that I used the "Track Markers" (CTRL+T) button on every point, because it's not a complicated scene. The movement is very small and almost on a 2D plane, not a 3D plane.
So I added 8 points (as seen in the image), and checked that they all matched the movement correctly.
[image: Pic 1]
(Amazing, it stabilizes my video when I press "L"!)

BUT, now when I go to the Layout panel, add an object constraint, and toggle "Motion Tracking" in "Viewport Overlays", nothing happens! The camera doesn't move, no points show up.
[image: Pic 2]
And I'm stuck and need to go to sleep. Could someone educate me as to what's going on?

All I want is to add some text to a scene, so I could walk past it, etc.
How can I achieve this? Please help!

Thanks in advance,
BeardWix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is **solving** the scene if you want motion reconstruction in 3d.

In the solve tab press **Solve Camera Motion**

[image]

Once the scene is solved, open the scene setup and press **Setup Tracking Scene**.

[image]

That will add a camera tracking constraint to the camera that is linked to the track information and camera solution.

To view the video through the camera view, press **Set as Background**

Additionally you could also add empties to the scene to match the trackers. Press **Link Empty to Track**

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Now all I need to do is to re-record my videos with dozens of trackers, since I can only find about 6 usable tracking points. Solved!

Comment: If you want to learn some more about tracking read this post that details a lot of the problems and solutions: [**How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking) also look in the internet for a series of videos called "**Track, Match, Blend**" by Sebastian Koenig. He explains the whole process very well.

Comment: In the image you posted there are plenty of elements that can be tracked. What matters is to have elements that cleary stand out from their surroundings and that can be recognized clearly by the trackers from one frame to the next. Use the cacuts, the base of the tree, the wall behind.

Comment: Haha, that video was a dummy video I was using to test the features. My ACTUAL video was much lower in contrast and frame rate, so I'm going to re-record it in 60fps, and put some trackers on the ground to make the process easier. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: Read the link. It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks, I've already been reading that up a bit. The only annoying thing is that those trackers are of absolutely NO help when the scene is outdoors! Sigh. Time to print out some new trackers that are more visible in the scene..